# Unable to access data in one class from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, instance-variables

Here is the class which gives me a modal view of the camera

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {
  UIImagePickerController *cameraView; // camera modal view
  BOOL isCameraLoaded;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImagePickerController *cameraView; 
- (IBAction)cameraViewbuttonPressed;
- (void)doSomething;
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize cameraView;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  cameraView = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  cameraView.sourceType =   UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
  cameraView.cameraOverlayView = cameraOverlayView;
  cameraView.delegate = self;
  cameraView.allowsEditing = NO;
  cameraView.showsCameraControls = NO;
}

- (IBAction)cameraViewbuttonPressed {       
 [self presentModalViewController:cameraView animated:YES];
 isCameraLoaded = YES;
}

- (void)doSomething {
  [cameraView takePicture];
  if ([cameraView isCameraLoaded]) printf("camera view is laoded");
  else {
    printf("camera view is NOT loaded");
  }
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [cameraView release];
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

In the app delegate when it's running, I call doSomething:

```
ViewController *actions = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[actions doSomething];
[actions release];
```

After I press the camera button, the cameraview loads
In the app delegate I call dosomething but nothing happens and I get null for the BOOL which returns "camera view is NOT loaded".

If I call doSomething in the `ViewController` class, it works fine, but from another class, it doesn't work.

How can I access the variables in `ViewController` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem isn't accessing the variables, it's that you're creating a new `ViewController` from scratch with `alloc`/`init` and then immediately trying to use it as if it were fully installed in the view hierarchy. Note that `cameraView` is set up inside `viewDidLoad`, which won't ever get called for the new view controller.

It sounds like you already have an instance of `ViewController` set up and working, so probably you should use that rather than creating a new one:

```
ViewController* actions = [self getMyExistingViewControllerFromSomewhere];
[actions doSomething];
```

If that is not the case, you'll need to add the newly created view to the appropriate superview and let it all initialise properly before trying to use it.

Comment: Holy cow, I wasn't expecting an answer so quickly!

Yes, the instance of ViewController is set up and working. 
I understand your logic, however, I don't know how to "getMyExistingViewControllerFromSomewhere".

Comment: Okay I fixed it, I initiated ViewController from the nib the first time as a "UIViewController" in the @interface, now I just switched "UIViewController" to "ViewController" (the class name). Then I used the pointer as "getMyExistingViewControllerFromSomewhere". You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Add to the .h:

```
@property (readwrite, assign, setter=setCameraLoaded) BOOL isCameraLoaded;
```

Add to the .m:

```
@synthesize isCameraLoaded;
```

You can then do:

```
if ([actions isCameraLoaded]) {
    [actions setCameraLoaded:FALSE];
}
```